# My question is about implementing white list gong'n through PHP Quickstart

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api

I want to use PHP QuickStart with Gmail API to implement whitelist or blacklist functions. If the sender is on the blacklist, it will be automatically spam, or only Gmail registered with the service can send letters to each other. How can we achieve this? Thank you.

I've implemented the reply email.

```html
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::MAIL_GOOGLE_COM);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

  if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

            $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

            // Prepare the message in message/rfc822
           if (isset($_SESSION['gmail_access_token']) &amp;&amp; !empty($_SESSION['gmail_access_token']) ) {
  
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['gmail_access_token']);
    $objGMail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
  
    $strSubject = 'this is test email message' . date('M d, Y h:i:s A');
  
    $strRawMessage = "From: My Mail <myemail@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "To: My Mail <noreply@gmail.com>\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "this is a test !\r\n";
  
    //Users.messages->send - Requires -> Prepare the message in message/rfc822
    try {
        // The message needs to be encoded in Base64URL
        $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
        $msg = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
        $msg->setRaw($mime);
  
        //The special value **me** can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        $objSentMsg = $objGMail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
  
        print('Message sent object');
        print($objSentMsg);
  
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print($e->getMessage());
        unset($_SESSION['gmail_access_token']);
    }
}
else {
    // Failed Authentication
    if (isset($_REQUEST['error'])) {
        //header('Location: ./index.php?error_code=1');
        echo "error auth";
    }
    else{
        // Redirects to google for User Authentication
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header("Location: $authUrl");
    }
}
```

If there is an implementation, please let me know. thank you.

Comment: it will be automatically spam = it will be automatically go in spam list。

Comment: title = My question is about implementing white list or black list through PHP Quickstart